# Почему появляется ошибка 404? Python, django

Tags: python, django

Здравствуйте. Учусь программировать на django. Почему появляется ошибка 404? Как это исправить?(Пользуюсь ListView,DetailView)

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import *

# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 255,verbose_name="Title")
    img = models.CharField(max_length = 255,verbose_name="Image")
    text = models.TextField()
    short_text = models.CharField(max_length = 70,verbose_name="short_text")
    alias = models.SlugField(max_length = 255,verbose_name="urlname")
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Post"
        verbose_name_plural = "Post's"
        def __str__(self):
            return 'Post %s' % self.title
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import PostsListView,PostDetailView
urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^$', PostsListView.as_view(),name="list"),
    url(r'^post/(?P<alias>\d+)$', PostDetailView.as_view()),
]
```

**post_list.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
body{
    text-align: center;
}
.wrapped{
    border:  3px solid red;
    margin:  0 auto ;
    max-width: 600px;
}

</style>
<body>
    <div class="title"><h1>{{title}}</h1></div>
    {% for post in object_list%}
    <div class="wrapped">
    <div class="name_post" >{{post.title}}</div>
    <div class="image"> <img src="{{post.img}}" alt=""> </div>
    <div class="short_text">{{post.short_text}}</div>
    <div class="href"> <a href="/post/{{post.alias}}">Show...</a></div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}


</body>
</html>
```

**post_detail.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Post</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
    body{
        text-align: center;
    }
    .wrapped{
        border: 3px solid green;
        margin:  0 auto ;
        width: 60%;
    }
</style>
<body>
    {% for post in object_list %}
    <div class="wrapped">
        <h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
        <div>{{post.text}}</div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from main.models import *
from django.http import Http404,HttpResponse
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.template import Context,Template
from .models import Post
# Create your views here.
from django.views.generic import ListView,DetailView

class PostsListView(ListView):
    model = Post
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
```

[image: Ошибка!!]

[image: Все норм (post_list.html)]

Comment: С адресами несостыковка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что в файле **urls.py** группа `<alias>` у Вас `\d+` принимает только цифры. Вам надо `[a-z0-9_]+` или что-то в этом роде.